# Google Task API Move Task to different list

Tags: google-tasks-api, google-tasks

I'd like to know if the Google Tasks API provides the option to move a task to a different list or if I need to create a copy of the task.

The move method seems to only allow moving within the same list.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [tasks API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/v1/reference/) does not support moving tasks from one list to another, just changing a tasks parent task or moving it to the top of the list.

You can however get the task with `/lists/tasklist_id/tasks/task_id`, check each of its fields and set populate the same fields with a different tasklist_id using `/lists/new_tasklist_id/tasks` and then delete the old one with `/lists/tasklist_id/tasks/task_id`

Google also provides the [Tasks API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/tasks/v1/) which should help you experiment.

Comment: Could you please give an example on how to move it to the top of the list? or to a different position in the list?

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm the answer by Thai Wood:

This is definitely the way to do it. I also moved a task using the website and and noticed that the task id changes, therefore the google website also seems to do a delete followed by a insert.